# Setting the value of a database-driven DropDownListFor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

There's a number of questions about this on SO already and I've looked through quite a few of them, but am still unable to figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong here. I'm able to have a dropdownlistfor populate the select values without any issue, but setting the value of the list from the database isn't working.

Basically the same select list is used multiple times on the page, and there is a seperate model variable that tracks the value for each instance. Here's an example of for the hdr_base_uom variable:

The model:

```
public string hdr_base_uom { get; set; }
public List<UomOption> putupOptions { get; set; }

public class UomOption
{
    public int uom_id { get; set; }
    public string uom_description { get; set; }
}
```

Populating the list:

```
public List<UomOption> GetPutupOptions()
{
    try
    {
        using (IfxConnection con = new IfxConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IBMCONN"].ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                List<UomOption> uomOptions= con.Query<UomOption>("select uom_id, initcap(uom_description) as uom_description " +
                    " from oe_unitom " +
                    " where uom_group = 1 order by uom_description").ToList();
                con.Close();
                uomOptions.Insert(0, new UomOption(){ uom_id = 0, uom_description = " "});
                return uomOptions;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw x;
        }
    }
```

The view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.hdr_base_uom, new SelectList(Model.putupOptions, 
    "uom_id", "uom_description", Model.hdr_base_uom), 
    new { disabled = "disabled", style = "width:13em" })
```

If I simply display the value of `model.hdr_base_uom` on the page then the `uom_id` that is set to that variable shows up. Attempting to use that ID to set the value of the `dropdownlistfor` does nothing, however. For example if the `uom_id` is `58` which has the corresponding description of `"Roll"` to be displayed, instead of defaulting to Roll the `dropdownlistfor` instead shows the first element in the list (the empty element added above.)

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `Model.hdr_base-uom` means. You don't need it though:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.hdr_base_uom, new SelectList(Model.putupOptions, 
    "uom_id", "uom_description"), 
    new { disabled = "disabled", style = "width:13em" })
```

Also ensure that you set `"58"` (or whatever the selected value should be, stringified) to `hdr_base_uom` field.

Your example works for me as is (with or without `Model.hdr_base-uom`) (in modern browsers, of course).

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/trzd9q)

Comment: That the code worked for you made me try experimenting some with the hdr_base_uom variable further. I'm not sure why it is, but hdr_base_uom being set from the database simply would not work. When I manually assigned hdr_base_uom = "90" it worked fine. I tried changing hdr_base_uom to being an int and that worked perfectly from the database fetch. I've no idea why, however. If you've got an explanation and can update your answer with it I'll mark it as correct since you put me on the path to a solution.

Comment: I wish I had an explanation. In the past, I have searched and even looked into the [source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/0ee98f84b41b6bef6bde6945e2797de9dac7d48a/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs#L335), but I can't quite put my finger on it. This is why I edited my answer. I guess somewhere between those expression trees and object conversions, it gets _lost in translation_! It is because of these quirks that I tend to stay away from `DropDownListFor` now-a-days.

Comment: How do you approach this functionality instead?

Comment: In my last few projects, I have been using Twitter Bootstrap, so the regular MVC helper won't cut it anyway. I have my own helper but you can use something like [this](https://github.com/JCherryhomes/BootstrapMvcHelpers/blob/master/BootstrapMvcHelpers/DropDown/DropDownHelper.cs). The other option is to go nuclear - directly building the HTML in the view. Saves me effort to go the extra mile of creating a SelectList just for the sake for the helper.

Comment: There is also [twitterbootstrapmvc](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com) but starting with Boostrap 3, they need a license to be purchased.